# The width and height for resulting SVG when Exporting

Tags: export, svg-format

I `Export` a `Graphics` object to SVG, but how do I control the bounding box in the resulting SVG file? Here's my code:

```
g1 = Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 4]]; 
g2 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]];
g3 = Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-1, -1}/2}]];
g = Show[g1, g2, g3, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]
Export["Mathematica.svg", g]
```

The result is an SVG image with `width="149pt"` and `height="99pt"`. How do I control these parameters in the code?

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the whitespace around the graphic?

Comment: I need the bounding box of the right shape and relative sizes of all elements to be correct. If you run my code with ImageSize -> {2000, 1000}, you will see that the contents don't even fit in the bounding box.

Answer (score 3):

(Outputs here are for *Mathematica* 11.1.0.)

You are exporting a circular object with equal width and height but specify larger width than the height via the `ImageSize -> {200, 100}` option. Hence some margins are added from the left and the right, but the height is kept as you specified (`height="99pt"` corresponds to the height `100` pts). With automatic width or height you get them equal:

```
StringCases[ExportString[Show[g1, g2, g3, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}], "SVG"], 
 "<svg" ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ ">"]
```

> ```
> {"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" \
> width=\"99pt\" height=\"99pt\" viewBox=\"0 0 99 99\" version=\"1.1\">"}
> ```

You do control these parameters via the `ImageSize` option but for some reason the values are only approximately equal to what you specify:

```
StringCases[ExportString[Show[g1, g2, g3, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 1000}], "SVG"], 
 "<svg" ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ ">"]
```

> ```
> {"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" \
> width=\"981pt\" height=\"981pt\" viewBox=\"0 0 981 981\" version=\"1.1\">"}
> ```

---

> If you run my code with `ImageSize -> {2000, 1000}`, you will see that the contents don't even fit in the bounding box.

When I render the exported SVG file with Internet Explorer or Firefox I do not see any cropping:

[image: screenshot]

Opening the file with Adobe Illustrator 17 also shows no cropping:

[image: screenshot2]